# How do I programmatically read/parse yml values using Spring Boot's SPEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-el

If I have an annotation where people can set an SPEL expression (it might have yaml/environment values), how would I parse this to find the actual values?

Example:

```
public @interface TestA
{
    String spel() default "";
}

@TestA( spel = "${some.value.in.app.yml}" )
public class Test {}
```

The application.yml:

```
some:
  value:
    in:
      app:
        yml: Something
```

How would I do this? Do I need to pass something special to the `SpelExpressionParser`?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `EmbeddedValueResolver`.

There are many examples across the framework; see the `JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` for example.